# In Excel, how can I update the value of a cell based on the sum of cells which meet a condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I need to calculate the total dollar amount of a specific item sold over its life. I'm entering orders into Excel, with columns for SKUs included in that order and their price. I have another sheet on which I'd like to list how much money that SKU has brought in thus far.

The simplest thing would be having that second sheet auto-update whenever a new order was entered into the first sheet, including which SKUs were purchased and for what price.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Like a [sumif](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)?

Comment: Or a pivot table.

Comment: I've never heard of a pivot table before but after looking it up I might be able to use that to group the data around the SKUs together. Thanks!

Also, I know of SUMIF but have never used it. That's probably the easiest way to do it if I'm understanding how it works correctly. I'm assuming I could use it to SUM only the cells that meet an SKU value criteria that's on the same row. So, basically summing only the values which have "59237" (for example) on the same row. Thanks!

Comment: If you can attach an image to your post it might make things easier to understand.

Comment: Screenshot, table, some kind of example to illustrate what you're on about would help mate

Answer (score 0):

This formula the column you're summing and the column with the SKU's have to be lined up to each other.

`=Sumifs( [Column You're Summing], [Column with the SKU], [Sku])`

To do the pivot table.

1. Highlight the table
2. Under `Insert` select `PivotTable`
3. In the pane, drag the SKU either to the filter (top-left) or rows (bottom-left) of the boxes in the bottom section of the pane. Then filter for that SKU or find it in the rows
4. Then pull the column you're summing into the Values (bottom-right), ensuring it's taking the sum not a count (it does this sometimes when there's text values)